# What is the proper way to append React Element to body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a really simple popover component, so I need to append some JSX directly to the body, and I can't find out how to do this using React.
Also, React Portals are unsuitable for my popover component.

Comment: This is not good to append a dom element directly to the body. It is better to use the render method of the component.

Comment: I thought about it, but there are some z-index issues, thats why I need to append content to the body, so my popover could be on the top level

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to generic without any code sample..

You should make use of the react lifecycle to do that. My guess is that you have a button that when clicked should trigger the popover. There is a number of ways to go from here.

In your render return add a button with an onClick function that updates the state to toggle a popoverVisible boolean value.

```
<button onClick={()=>this.togglePopoverVisible()}>Open popover</button>
```

The function should be like this:

```
togglePopoverVisible() {
    this.setState({
        popoverVisible: !this.state.popoverVisible
    });
}
```

In your render again make sure to show the popover when it's visible:

```
let popover = [];
if (this.state.popoverVisible) {
   popover = <div className="popover"></div>
}
```

Finally in your render return add somewhere:

```
{popover}
```

That is the main idea, you create an action and when triggered you update the state of the component. According the the new state you add or remove elements to the DOM tree. In these types of scenarios I always prefer to update a class toggling the visibility though instead of adding/removing dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

In ComponentWillmount
you can use below Code:

```
ComponentWillmount() {
  this.struct = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(this.struct);}
```